# How to install docker-compose on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic installed on Asus tinker board. 
I have installed docker `17.12.1-ce` from ubuntu repository

```
apt-get install docker.io
```

after this i need to install `docker-compose`. when i try to check docker compose version using

```
docker-compose -v
/user/local/bin/docker-compose: lin1: Not: command not found
```

docker compose isn't installing. Please guide

Answer (score 3):

First download the docker-compose. Below is the command to download the latest version.

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Once you have downloaded to /usr/local/bin/ folder, provide the execute permission to file.

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Then create symbolic link with below command. Once you create symbolic link, you will be able to use the docker-compose command.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

For more information check the [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried and got the following error.

Comment: and the issue still persists, docker-compose command not found

Comment: i've installed docker & docker compose on ubuntu 16.04 xenial and it works fine. Now i'm following same process to install docker & docker compose on ubuntu 18.04 Bionic and facing this issue.

Comment: @SaqibJutt When you run the command with full path does it work? /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -v

Comment: Are you using correct path? The path you have provided in your question seems to be wrong. You are using /user instead of /usr.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install docker-compose too

```
apt-get install docker-compose
```

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried but still command not found.